# How to extract values from a json object with python?

Tags: json, python-2.7

I've a data frame in which one column contains json object named as cast_and_crew.
I need to take the value of the key 'person_name' and store it in a separate data frame.
The data frame which contains cast_and_crew json is given in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zZJv.png)
please refer this image too. [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68ED8.png)

> The json inside one row looks like

```
[
 {'characterName': '', 'creditType': 'Actor', 'personName':'M.A.Nadiadwala'},
 {'characterName': '', 'creditType': 'Actor',
 'personName': 'Gyandev Agnihotri'},
 {'characterName': '', 'creditType': 'Actor', 
'personName': 'Rakesh Kumar'}
]
```

the column cast_and_crew is a list
 
`(type(movie_details.iloc[0]['cast_and_crew'])`
`Out[18]: list)`
inside which it contains dictionaries of key value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for read this json i am unable to understand your o/p format so you can continue after that ...

```
cast_and_crew =[
   {'characterName':'','creditType':'Actor','personName':'M.A.Nadiadwala'},
   {'characterName': '', 'creditType': 'Actor',
    'personName': 'Gyandev Agnihotri'},
   {'characterName': '', 'creditType': 'Actor', 
    'personName': 'Rakesh Kumar'}
]
for data in cast_and_crew:
    # for python3 use print(data.get('personName'))
    print data.get('personName')
```

O/P:

```
M.A.Nadiadwala
M.A.Nadiadwala
M.A.Nadiadwala
```

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'.

Comment: i'm getting error - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df = df.cast_and_crew.apply(lambda x: x[0]['personName']).to_frame(name='personName')
```

Should do the trick. I can't really test it since you didn't paste the dataframe in a copy-pasteable manner.

edit: This only takes the first item of the list. I'm not sure what your output is supposed to be so perhaps i answered a bit too quickly. Can you please give an example output of what you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html). It will get your json attribute into one column and then you can concatenate that dataframe into the original cast_and_crew dataframe by using

```
frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```